# Upgrade from Zend Framework 1.11 to 1.12 causes WSOD

Tags: zend-framework, bootstrapping

I am running Centos 6.3. I have used Yum to install php-ZendFramework. I have an app that is running just fine using the default auth adapter.

I performed a 'yum update' and php-ZendFramework 1.12.0 was installed. Now, when I run my app I get a white screen of death. Nothing else changed.

If I put a die("foo") at the end of my Bootstrap I see "Foo". If I put it as the first line in my auth controller action I get WSOD.

From what I am reading, this MAY be related to the new autoloader that was back-ported from Zend 2. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to resolve this problem?

Here is my Bootstrap:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

protected function _initAutoload()
{
    $modelLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_AutoLoader(array(
        'namespace' => '',
        'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH));

    /*********************************************************
      These lines force login if not already logged in                           
    *********************************************************/
    $acl = new Model_SystemAcl;
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    $fc = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $fc->registerPlugin(new Plugin_AccessCheck($acl,$auth));
    /*********************************************************/

    return $modelLoader;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Zend changed the distribution. I did a yum install php-ZendFramework* to get a full install and everything works now.